# Unable to hold QQmlContext in std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, qt, stl, qml, shared-ptr

I noticed some quite strange behavior when working with Qt 5.15/C++.

I was working on a small application when I wanted to set a context property for my root context.

My application is a QtQuick app which uses `QQmlApplicationEngine` instead of `QQuickView` (which was, for whatever reason, the default when creating a Qt Quick app):

```cpp
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));

// ...

QStringList entryList { "String1", "String2", "String3" };
```

Then, when assigning the string list as a context property for my root context, I wanted to use STL shared pointers instead of raw pointers:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<QQmlContext> context = std::make_shared<QQmlContext>(engine.rootContext());

if (!context) {
    qDebug() << "Failed to get root context. exiting.";
    exit(-1);
}

context->setContextProperty("entryList", QVariant::fromValue(entryList));
```

My entry list will be empty inside QML.

However, when I use raw pointers:

```cpp
QQmlContext* context = engine.rootContext();

// ...
```

everything works just fine and the `entryList` var is filled inside QML.

**Is there a logical behaviour behind this which I don't yet understand?**

By the way, when using `QSharedPointer`s instead of `shared_ptr`, The list will be filled, however I'm getting a debugger exception on exit:

> Exception at 0x7ff8022f2933, code: 0xc0000005: read access violation at: 0xffffffffffffffff, flags=0x0 (first chance)

Comment: In many cases with QT, when you create an instance of something its ownership is often transferred to its parent, so you will find that you don't need to manage the lifetime yourself.  If you use a shared-ptr there will probably be a double-delete since (at cleanup) the QmlEngine will delete all contexts and then the context will be deleted again when the shared-ptr refcount hits zero.

Comment: @Den-Jason so does that mean I won't have to take care of memory management for those pointers, e.g., calling `delete` resp. connecting signals to a `deleteLater()` slot?

Comment: @taiBsu If the object has a parent then it is not necessary to use delete or deleteLater as that is the parent's job.

Comment: thanks a lot for pointing this out. Would any of you be able to form an eloquent answer for this question based on that information so I can set a solution for that problem?

Comment: @taiBsu Note that the engine creates the "context", so you don't think that class handles its memory? Qt points out in the docs explicitly when it does not handle memory such as when QNetworkManager returns a QNetworkReply

Comment: @eyllanesc Indeed you're right, I didn't think about that at this very moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt clearly indicates when the developer must manage the memory of an object, if it does not indicate it then it must be assumed that Qt will eliminate it when necessary.

In this particular case the QQmlContext is created by QQmlApplicationEngine so it is the responsibility of that class to manage its memory. For example, a different case is QNetworkAccessManager is that in the docs it indicates that the developer must handle the memory of the created QNetworkReply([docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#details)):

> Note: After the request has finished, it is the responsibility of the user to delete the QNetworkReply object at an appropriate time. Do not directly delete it inside the slot connected to finished(). You can use the deleteLater() function.

The memory management that Qt is responsible for can be done through the QObject hierarchy or use its own pointers (QPointer, QSharedPointer, etc) but that is irrelevant for the developer since that is part of the private Qt API.